# How to fix the error "Receiver class org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateExtensionContext does not define or inherit an implementation"?

Tags: java, junit, junit5, parameterized-unit-test

I have the following parameterized JUnit5 test that is supposed to take input data from the method `testData`

```
import com.nimbusds.jose.JOSEException;
import com.nimbusds.jose.JWSHeader;
import com.nimbusds.jose.JWSSigner;
import com.nimbusds.jose.crypto.MACSigner;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.JWTClaimsSet;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.SignedJWT;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.Arguments;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodSource;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static com.nimbusds.jose.JWSAlgorithm.HS256;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.Arguments.arguments;
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED;
import static org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity.status;

class JwtModifierControllerValidationTest {
    private final static String SECRET_KEY = "xG5Zamg9VHr0al0ob+LDsnMxEdLFNvOiPCiV8Cq3xgM=";

    static Stream<Arguments> testData() throws JOSEException {
        final JWSSigner signer = new MACSigner(SECRET_KEY);
        final SignedJWT inputJwt1 = new SignedJWT(new JWSHeader(HS256),
                new JWTClaimsSet.Builder()
                        .subject("test")
                        .build()
        );
        inputJwt1.sign(signer);

        final String validAuthHeader = String.format("Bearer %s", inputJwt1.serialize());

        final String invalidAuthHeader = validAuthHeader.substring(0, validAuthHeader.length() - 2);

        return Stream.of(
                arguments(validAuthHeader, "",
                        status(BAD_REQUEST).body("Empty expiration date parameter")),
                arguments(validAuthHeader, "YYY-adsf-1",
                        status(BAD_REQUEST).body("Invalid expiration date parameter")),
                arguments("", "2023-05-01",
                        status(BAD_REQUEST).body("Empty token")),
                arguments(invalidAuthHeader, "2023-05-01",
                        status(UNAUTHORIZED).body("Invalid token"))
        );
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("testData")
    public void givenInputData_whenModifyJwt_thenReturnCorrectResult(final String authorizationHeader, final String newExpirationDate, final ResponseEntity<String> expectedResult) {
        // Given
        final JwtModifierController sut = new JwtModifierController();
        sut.secretKey = SECRET_KEY;

        // When
        final ResponseEntity<String> actualResult = sut.modifyJwt(authorizationHeader,
                newExpirationDate);

        // Then
        assertEquals(expectedResult, actualResult);
    }
}
```

The `pom.xml` file contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>13</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>13</maven.compiler.target>
        <jjwt.version>0.11.5</jjwt.version>
        <junit.version>5.9.3</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.32</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
            <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>9.31</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

When I run the test I get the following error:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateExtensionContext does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExecutableInvoker getExecutableInvoker()' of interface org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext.

    at org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodArgumentsProvider.lambda$provideArguments$2(MethodArgumentsProvider.java:60)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:274)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1621)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:274)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1621)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateTestDescriptor.execute(TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java:107)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateTestDescriptor.execute(TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java:42)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1507)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1507)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
    Suppressed: org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException: Configuration error: You must configure at least one set of arguments for this @ParameterizedTest
        at org.junit.platform.commons.util.Preconditions.condition(Preconditions.java:299)
        at org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTestExtension.lambda$provideTestTemplateInvocationContexts$5(ParameterizedTestExtension.java:98)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.close(AbstractPipeline.java:323)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:271)
        ... 54 more
```

Before that I was getting the error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean org.junit.platform.commons.util.CollectionUtils.isConvertibleToStream(java.lang.Class)'` which I fixed by adding the following dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

How can I make the above test run?

Comment: *Configuration error: You must configure at least one set of arguments for this @ParameterizedTest* the message sounds pretty clear. *testData* returns an empty stream

Comment: @Jens `@MethodSource("testData")` is already there. `testData` returns  `Stream<Arguments>`. What additional set of arguments needs to be configured there?

Comment: Have you tried to debug if you get a Stream with atleast one argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the `testData()` is throwing an exception. To simplify the question, try running this test: you'll a similar exception with the same message:

```java
static Stream<Arguments> testData() throws Exception {
    if(true)
        throw new RuntimeException("");
    return Stream.of(
            arguments("a", 1),
            arguments("b", 2),
            arguments("c", 3)
    );
}

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("testData")
public void givenInputData_whenModifyJwt_thenReturnCorrectResult(final String str, final int nr) {
    System.out.println(str + nr);
    // ==> Configuration error: You must configure at least one set of arguments for this @ParameterizedTest
}
```

In order to make it more visible, you can catch the error and *fail* the test:

```java
static Stream<Arguments> testData() {
    try {
        // preparing test arguments 
        // return Stream.of(...);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Assertions.fail("testData() threw exception while setting up the test. ", e);
        return Stream.empty();
    }
}
```

As a result, you'll have a failed test with a better error message.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps less likely to occur, but in case anyone runs into the same problem as I did, my maven-surefire-plugin was configured with a different version of JUnit than my actual tests.

In other words, my pom.xml looked something like:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.10.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- ... -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>5.8.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Note the discrepancy: 5.10.2 and 5.8.2!

I was still receiving the same error after deleting the entire contents of the repository except an test and an empty method source.

To avoid the problem in the future, use a variable:

```xml
<properties>
    <junit.version>5.10.2</junit.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- ... -->
            <dependencies>
                <!-- ... -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>${junit.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The actual error I was getting:

> Receiver class org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateExtensionContext does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExecutableInvoker getExecutableInvoker()' of interface org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext.